# How to link Google Play account to a Google Developer Project

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I have use the google play developer console and want to set the API access. I have a google developer project before so I want to add the exist project.

I follow the documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#using_an_existing_api_project):

> Using an existing API project
>
> If you are already a user of the Google Play Developer API, you can
>   link to your existing API project by following these steps. If the API
>   project you want to link to is not listed, verify that your Google
>   Play Developer Console account is designated as an Owner, and the
>   Google Play Developer API is enabled.
>
> 1. Go to the API Access page on the Google Play Developer Console.
> 2. Accept the API Terms of Service.
> 3. Choose the project you’d like to link.
> 4. Click Link.
>
> Your Google Play Developer Console is now linked to the API project.

However, in my API Access page, there is only `Create new project` button, and I don't know to follow the steps to link the exist one. There is no project listed.

Does anyone have ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 51):

Ensure the following:

> If you are already a user of the Google Play Developer API, you can link to your existing API project by following these steps. If the API project you want to link to is **not listed**, verify that your Google Play Developer Console account is designated as an **Owner**, and the **Google Play Developer API** is **enabled**.

Login to [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) and navigate to project you want to link to google play developer console, then:

1. Choose "API Manager" from left menu
2. Click "Enable API"
3. Search for "Google Play Developer API"
4. Click to view details and then click "Enable"

Done. Now you can go back to your [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) and refresh API Access page. Your project should be listed.

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver. Note: the API is now called "Google Play Android Developer API".

Comment: If my Google Cloud Project is on different account and my Google Play developer console account is different i.e.both account registered with different email ids,can I link them???

Comment: Thank you so much. I think Google Play Console should mention this from the linking page.

Answer (score 10):

Now like this

### Step 1

[image]

---

### Step 2

---

[image]

### Step 3

[image]